# Blender drops last few seconds of video from imported MP4 (with correct framerate)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, import, video, movie-clip-editor

I'm importing a ~15 minute .mp4 into blender using the "Add Movie" feature.  My problem is that the video track is missing the last ~2 seconds of video.

The frame rate is set correctly (25fps)--verified not only by checking the frame rate using external software but also by the fact that the audio and video are perfectly in sync throughout the entire video.

If I play the video using an external video player I can verify that the last couple of seconds do exist.

What are some things that could be causing this? I can't find any similar problems or relevant suggestions using Google searches--potentially because they are buried by similar problems caused by users setting the incorrect frame rate.

Comment: Difficult to say, too little info, apart not having that video available, I guess: and, which Blender version? Have you tried other versions, if this could be a bug? Does it happen only with that video?